# How to cluster an application

Tags: java, distributed-computing, high-availability

I am sorry if the following question has already been answered or if it is simply not specific enough yet I am entirely new to the topic of clustered applications and I am looking for a starting point right now.

My goal is to write a software which will perform a variety of different tasks, primarily starting other software on remote servers. This software needs to calculate how many instance of these other softwares are currently required and will then have to somehow tell the remote server to launch new instances.

The software which is requesting new instance must not be unavailable or crash, though, which is why I am looking to distribute it onto multiple servers and then coordinate these instances to work simultaneously and take over if any instance crashes so that the system as a whole is somewhat resilient.

The application itself should either be reachable via a REST API or via a TCP connection, whereas I would prefer the former one. If you know any framework which might help me with this I would be pleased if you could let me know.

Best regards

PS.: I have seen that Spring provides some support for distributed system but I am unsure if that would really help me with my task.

Comment: IMO this question is far too broad. There are countless ways to do this, many library/framework options, etc. ("Cluster analysis", btw, is something completely different. Until there are actual programming questions, the transport mechanism is totally irrelevant.)

Answer (score 0):

Let me divide your questions into parts

> 1. You want your applications to do some tasks
> 2. Your applications are multiple for high availability purposes
> 3. You want some sort of a mechanism for your applications to communicate and pass messages
> 4. You want your application to be reachable (REST API or TCP) preferably REST

Well the answer to your first 3 questions lies in not implementing all of it yourself but use a distributed cache for your purposes. A Distributed Cache or an In-Memory Data Grid is clustered in nature and provides high availability for production environments. Scalabiilty is plus for you though.

What you could do is deploy as many as your applications you want and use the Cache/IMDG to provide high availability and a platform/medium for you to use to coordinate actions. Features like writer locks can guarantee no two applications are performing the same task or more than it was required.

Lastly, regarding creating a reachable REST API for your applications, simply deploy your applications as web based applications and use the distributed cache underneath.

**Disclosure:** I work for Alachisoft. An In-Memory Distributed Cache provider. We have two products, one for linux and one for .Windows, both server .NET and Java applications and objects from both the languages are interchangeable. A feature of TayzGrid and NCache